# How to Pass Flutter List of Images with Null values

Tags: flutter

I am passing image url and if value is null, I get error . How can i ignore null and just show images where there is value.

```
Carousel(
                  images: [
                    Image.network(this.widget.product.productPhoto, fit: BoxFit.fill,),
                    Image.network(this.widget.product.photo1, fit: BoxFit.fill),
                    Image.network(this.widget.product.photo2, fit: BoxFit.fill),
                    Image.network(this.widget.product.photo3, fit: BoxFit.fill),
                    Image.network(this.widget.product.photo4, fit: BoxFit.fill),
                    Image.network(this.widget.product.photo5, fit: BoxFit.fill),
                  ],
                ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an `if` condition inside your array

```dart
Carousel(
                  images: [
                    if(this.widget.product.productPhoto != null)
                    Image.network(this.widget.product.productPhoto, fit: BoxFit.fill,),

                    if(this.widget.product.photo1 != null)
                    Image.network(this.widget.product.photo1, fit: BoxFit.fill),


                   //same for images below 
                    Image.network(this.widget.product.photo2, fit: BoxFit.fill),
                    Image.network(this.widget.product.photo3, fit: BoxFit.fill),
                    Image.network(this.widget.product.photo4, fit: BoxFit.fill),
                    Image.network(this.widget.product.photo5, fit: BoxFit.fill),
                  ],
                ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Add check using `if` statement, add similar for others.

```
if(this.widget.product.productPhoto != null)
    Image.network(this.widget.product.productPhoto, fit: BoxFit.fill,),
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can do :

```
 Image.network(this.widget.product.productPhoto != null?  this.widget.product.productPhoto : "default image address", fit: BoxFit.fill,),
```

Comment: As this is list of images and have dot indicator as well for images, I wanted to ignore Images if value is null. This solution works perfectly `if(this.widget.product.photo1 != null)
                    Image.network(this.widget.product.photo1, fit: BoxFit.fill),`

Comment: Yes, If you want to ignore images you can use `if(this.widget.product.photo1 != null)                     Image.network(this.widget.product.photo1, fit: BoxFit.fill),` but if you want to show default image  you can use above code.